# Starting chrome via `chrome-headless-render-pdf` fails (2023)

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

When running chrome via `chrome-headless-render-pdf`
( Node.js script https://github.com/Szpadel/chrome-headless-render-pdf ),
I get error, that I cannot yet understand what to do with it.

Versions:

- Google Chrome 112.0.5615.49 (and with Google Chrome 112.0.5615.121)
- chrome-headless-render-pdf 1.11.0

Error Log:

```
Using /usr/bin/google-chrome
Waiting for chrome to became available
Detected ipv4 connection
Chrome port open!
Chrome stopped (null)
(chrome) (out) 
(chrome) (err) qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped
(chrome) (err) qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped
(chrome) (err) [0417/090555.189718:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
(chrome) (err) [0417/090555.285522:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
(chrome) (err) [0417/090555.286453:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
(chrome) (err) [0417/090555.300120:ERROR:file_path_watcher_inotify.cc(315)] inotify_init() failed: Function not implemented (38)
(chrome) (err) 
(chrome) (err) DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49238/devtools/browser/ec0a1593-97aa-4a19-8360-7ceb4b950e68
(chrome) (err) qemu: unknown option 'type=utility'
(chrome) (err) [0417/090555.613256:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
(chrome) (err) [0417/090555.617069:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(936)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=1002
(chrome) (err) [0417/090555.617211:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1292)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)
(chrome) (err) [0417/090555.635196:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(541)] Network service crashed, restarting service.
(chrome) (err) qemu: unknown option 'type=utility'
(chrome) (err) [0417/090555.688126:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(936)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=1002
(chrome) (err) [0417/090555.688202:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1292)] The GPU process has crashed 2 time(s)
(chrome) (err) [0417/090555.697249:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(541)] Network service crashed, restarting service.
(chrome) (err) qemu: unknown option 'type=utility'
(chrome) (err) [0417/090555.722214:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(936)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=1002
(chrome) (err) [0417/090555.722285:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1292)] The GPU process has crashed 3 time(s)
(chrome) (err) [0417/090555.722377:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(440)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
(chrome) (err) [0417/090555.724842:ERROR:scoped_ptrace_attach.cc(27)] ptrace: Function not implemented (38)
(chrome) (err) qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped
(chrome) (err) 
Chrome port open!
Chrome port open!
```

---

chrome and `chrome-headless-render-pdf`  are running in docker.

Chrome is installed as

```bash
FROM ubuntu:22.04 AS linux_with_chrome

# Installing latest Chrome directly from Google repository
# check actual version at https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome?dist=stable
# TODO install Chrome of specific version, check links in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334876/how-to-install-google-chrome-version-88-for-ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
# Install wget.
RUN apt-get install -y wget
# dependency of Chrome
RUN apt-get install -y gnupg
# Set the Chrome key and repository.
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
# Install Chrome.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable
```